# Cocoapods local repo grabbing all files other than frameworks

Tags: git, cocoapods

Ive been having a problem of only textfiles being downloaded during pod install.  Originally I had the googlemobile ads cocoapods repo by itself now I am currently attempting to add a local repository for the AdobeCreativeSDK.  I have managed to be able to download all files from google and from my local repo except the frameworks in my local repo.  My PodFile is

```
project 'BonziTeam.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BonziTeam' do
pod ‘GoogleMobileAds’
pod ‘AdobeCreativeSDK‘, :git => 'ssh://ashley_alvarado@bugz.bonzitech.com/repos/libraries/ios_creative_sdk.git', :tag => 'v0.13.2139'
#   source 'ssh://ashley_alvarado@bugz.bonzitech.com/repos/libraries/ios_creative_sdk.git' 
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for BonziTeam

end
```

And my podspec file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
 spec.name               = 'AdobeCreativeSDK'
 spec.version            = '0.13.2139'
 spec.license            = { :type => 'BSD' }
 spec.homepage           = 'https://www.bonziteam.com'
 spec.authors            = { 'Ashley Alvarado' => 'ashley.alvarado@gobonzi.com' }
 spec.summary            = 'Adobes private sdk, largely used for aviary'
 spec.source             = { :git => 'ssh://ashley_alvarado@bugz.bonzitech.com/repos/libraries/ios_creative_sdk.git', :tag => '0.13.2139' }
 spec.platform    = :ios, '9.0'
 spec.requires_arc = false
 spec.source_files = '*', '*.framwork', 'AdobeCreativeSDKAssetModel.{h,m}'
 spec.resources = '*', 'AdobeCreativeSDKAssetModel.{h,m}', '*.framework'
 spec.frameworks = 'AdobeCreativeSDKAssetModel', 'AdobeCreativeSDKColor', 'AdobeCreativeSDKImage', 'AdobeCreativeSDKAssetUX', 'AdobeCreativeSDKCommonUX', 'AdobeCreativeSDKMarketUX', 'AdobeCreativeSDKAppLibraryUX', 'AdobeCreativeSDKBehance', 'AdobeCreativeSDKCore'
end
```

As you can see I have just throwing a few things at it attempting to get the frameworks to pass along with the rest of the files, all the others files being passed in of the local repo are just text files essentially. I still do get the googlemobileads fully framework and all.  So I was hoping someone had a solution as what I've found online has not fully explained it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get this work after putting it off for a few days and attempting a variety of methods.

Ended up being all that was needed was

```
vendored_frameworks
```

and commenting out the

```
frameworks, source_files and resources
```

.  Also, because in difficulty integrating the pod files into the project after they were actually being passed but failing on the install every time I had to revert to 0.39.0, since it appears that

```
pod install --no-integrate
```

is not supported in v1.0.